# 7 Up: Spelling out of numerals

Tags: numbers

Do I spell out "7+" as in "The odds ratio for a suicide attempt in adulthood ranged from 2.3 in those with one early life trauma to 29.8 in those with 7+ adverse childhood experiences" to "more than seven" or "seven or more"?

Comment: Well, "7+" is already ambiguous, as it's unclear whether it means "seven or more" or "more than seven".

Comment: @choster "The odds ratio for a suicide attempt in adulthood ranged from 2.3 in those with one early life trauma to 29.8 in those with 7+ adverse childhood experiences."

Comment: @choster Ok, I will.

Answer (score 1):

"n+" (as opposed to "> n") is usually meant as "n or more" since "n" is counted in the desired cardinal set. "n plus" may be used in colloquial speech as well.